# EKS nodeSelector results in pending pod

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, nodeselector, kubernetes-label

I am encountering problems when using `nodeSelector` in my Kubernetes manifest. I have a nodegroup in EKS with the label `eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup=dev-nodegroup`. This node has a name with the corresponding ip, as usual in AWS. If I set the `nodeName` in the manifest, everything works and the pod is deployed in the corresponding node but when I do:

```
nodeSelector:
      eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup: dev-nodegroup
```

in my manifest, at the same indentation level as the `containers` there is a `FailedScheduling`

```
 Warning  FailedScheduling  3m31s (x649 over 11h)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had no available disk.
```

Am I doing something wrong? I would also like to add the `zone` label to the node selector but it yields the same problem.

What does 'had no available disk' mean? I have chechedk my node doing `df -h` and there is enough free disk space. I have seen other questions where the output is that the node is unreachable or have some taint, mine doesn't have any.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have a volume mounted in the pod like this:

```
volumes:
    - name: <VOLUME_NAME>
      awsElasticBlockStore:
        volumeID: <EBS_ID>
        fsType: ext4
```

Since EBS are deployed only in one `zone` I would need to set the `zone` selector as well.

Also I have this storageClass (just noticed it):

```
Name:            gp2
IsDefaultClass:  Yes
Annotations:     kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"},"name":"gp2"},"parameters":{"fsType":"ext4","type":"gp2"},"provisioner":"kubernetes.io/aws-ebs","volumeBindingMode":"WaitForFirstConsumer"}
,storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class=true
Provisioner:           kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
Parameters:            fsType=ext4,type=gp2
AllowVolumeExpansion:  <unset>
MountOptions:          <none>
ReclaimPolicy:         Delete
VolumeBindingMode:     WaitForFirstConsumer
Events:                <none>
```

**EDIT2**

My cluster has only one nodegroup with one node, in case this helps, too.

Comment: do you use any persistentvolume? if you do, can you post your storageclass and persistentvolumeclaim spec to the question?

Comment: Hi, @gohm'c I use an EBS mounted as a volume like in the edit

Comment: the ebs volume and your worker node **both** reside in **same** availability zone?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it would not deploy the pod when I set the nodeName instead.

Answer (score 1):

`Yes, otherwise it would not deploy the pod when I set the nodeName instead`

For EBS volume it can only mount to a node once. The second time you run a pod trying to mount the **same volume on the same node** you will get this error. For your case, you should delete the pod that currently have the volume mounted since you only have 1 node (given your error: `default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had no available disk.`), before you run another pod that would mount the same volume again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. How can I do that from the manifest? When I use nodeName I don't get this error and the EBS is already attached to the previous pod.

Comment: By the way, I didn't mention it in the OP but I have two replicas of the pod using the EBS volume. My bad there.